# What is Edgic in terms of 'Survivor'?

Tags: survivor

[In an interview with Erika Casupanan](https://ew.com/tv/survivor-41-erika-casupanan-winner-finale-interview/), she refers to something about the edit participants receive as 'Edgic':

> Oh, the edit is one that I have a lot of really complicated feelings
> about, because leaving the game, I had no ego about how I was going to
> be shown. I was really proud of the way I played. I kind of accepted
> that whatever was gonna get shown would be shown. But, at the same
> time I've been a fan of the show for so long. So I'm aware of "Edgic"
> and I'm aware of what a winner's edit looks like.

Who or what is Edgic?

Answer (score 5):

It's a portmanteau of edit + logic. A way of determining in advance, based on edits of each character per episode, who might be the winner.

https://insidesurvivor.com/survivor-edgic-an-introduction-3094

Answer (score 3):

[Finally found it](https://insidesurvivor.com/survivor-edgic-an-introduction-3094)

What Is Edgic?

Edgic is a portmanteau that combines the words Editing and Logic. It is a concept that was originally devised by the good folks on the Survivor Sucks forums to try and determine the winner of each Survivor season based on the edit. Edgic assigns a rating to each player per episode based on their portrayal, the percentage of screen-time, and other varying factors. While Edgic was created to determine the winner, it is also a useful tool for mapping a character’s objective story arc throughout the season.